# Simple OmniAuth-Twitter failing to create new user because of validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, twitter-oauth

I am loosely following Railscasts Simple OmniAuth http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth to create my Twitter login. When I try to sign in and create a new user through twitter, I get the following message:

```
Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Name is not valid., Email can't be blank, Email is not valid.
```

If I hit the refresh button, I get the following error:

```
OAuth::Unauthorized 401 Unauthorized
```

I've already set my callback URL to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback` but I still get that message. I'm testing on localhost.

I modeled my users after Hartl's railstutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book and my website project requires that users have those fields filled in.

Unlike the railscasts, I created a new method to handle omniauth logins:

sessions_controller.rb

```
def omniauth_create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || 
         User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to user
end
```

user.rb

```
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid = auth["uid"]
    user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
  end
end
```

**Question: How do I bypass the validations?**

So far, I've tried using `skip_before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:omniauth_create]`, but that didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to skip the validations.  Either you can skip them all by passing `:validate => false` to the create method (usually A Bad Idea), or you can modify your validations to something like the following:

user.rb

```
validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => :password_required?

def password_required?
  !provider.blank? && super
end
```

Comment: It looks like name and email is also failing validation. If I follow your method, does this mean I'd have to write 2 more methods to test if name and email is required?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, you would create two more methods in a similar fashion to the above.  You may want to make sure that is really what you want though - not having name and email really limits the functionality you can build involving user data.

Comment: This is my first time getting data from an outside source. Is there a way for me to assign my name field to the user's twitter name and my email field to the user's twitter email?

Comment: Absolutely.  Check out the omniauth part 1 railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

Comment: Keep in mind though that different services provide different information.  For example, IIRC the twitter API provides one name field (rather than first and last name) and does not provide an email.

Comment: One more piece of advice: don't use localhost or 127.0.0.1 for the callback url, as most oauth providers won't route to that URL.  Instead, use lvh.me - it always goes to localhost (it is assigned to an IP of 127.0.0.1).